# nginx x-cache status flipping between hit and expired on WordPress site (test php file OK)

Tags: nginx, cache, wordpress

I have an nginx cache setup for a WordPress site, and it is flipping between nginx header status `x-cache: HIT` and `x-cache: EXPIRED` seemingly randomly:

```
C:\Users\curl-7.48>curl -I http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 14:15:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
X-Cached: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 14:15:12 GMT
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=vfuo4s72b2ffulacumgu9aidf0; path=/
Link: <http://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://example.com/>; rel=shortlink
Z_LOCATION: PHP MAIN
URI: /index.php
X-Cache: HIT

C:\Users\curl-7.48>curl -I http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 14:15:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
X-Cached: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 14:15:16 GMT
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=fbd37bsvi27cd3hcmrcg4lsio6; path=/
Link: <http://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://example.com/>; rel=shortlink
Z_LOCATION: PHP MAIN
URI: /index.php
X-Cache: EXPIRED     

C:\Users\curl-7.48>curl -I http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 14:15:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
X-Cached: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 14:15:43 GMT
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dkngc066edc1apnogulga1mtg4; path=/
Link: <http://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://example.com/>; rel=shortlink
Z_LOCATION: PHP MAIN
URI: /index.php
X-Cache: HIT
```

I also have a simple time.php script that always shows hit: `<?php echo time(); ?>`

```
C:\Users\curl-7.48\bin>curl -I http://example.com/time.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 14:26:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Z_LOCATION: PHP MAIN
URI: /time.php
X-Cache: HIT
```

**Questions Please:**

1. I am caching to /dev/shm/nginx. Any pointers on what is going on and how to fault find (memory usage is fine, there is no memory page swapping to disk, inodes are fine)?
2. Is this to do with my PHP app returning headers which are forcing nginx to not cache? Any way to detect this? I cant see any headers which say this in the CURL output (unless i am missing something)?
3. Does the ordering matter of the `fastcgi_pass php;` should this be at the start or the end of the `location ~ \.php$` block?
4. Also how would one find the actual file that is the cached page for `time.php` within `/dev/shm/nginx`... (there are lots of first level dirs `0x0-0xf`, then a second directory of `0x00 to 0xff`)?
5. When running `fatrace` I cannot see that the /dev/shm/nginx is being read - am i missing something there? Is nginx caching recently read files to a local memory store?
6. I setup cache logging as per [My pages are not getting served from cache.But nginx is actually caching the files](https://serverfault.com/questions/494477/my-pages-are-not-getting-served-from-cache-but-nginx-is-actually-caching-the-fil) and see I am getting lots of `"GET /all/?source=p1& HTTP/1.1" BYPASS` and `"GET /video/aab HTTP/1.1" EXPIRED` entries, is this related?

**My nginx config is below:**

```
http
{
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 15s;
    proxy_send_timeout  15s;
    proxy_read_timeout  15s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 15s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 15s;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;

    fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYCACHE:512m max_size=4096m inactive=120m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

    server
    {
        server_name example.com;
        root /home/example/public_html/;
        index index.php;

        access_log /home/example/logs/access.log;
        error_log  /home/example/logs/error.log;

        # Rules to work out when cache should or should not be used
        set $skip_cache 0;

        # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
        if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        if ($query_string != "") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
        if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
        if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            fastcgi_cache_valid 200 120m;
            fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
            fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

            fastcgi_cache MYCACHE;
            fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

            #more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Pragma";
            add_header Z_LOCATION "PHP MAIN"; add_header URI $uri; # DEBUG
            add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

            fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~ /purge(/.*) {
            fastcgi_cache_purge MYCACHE "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be based on my nginx config, which I've refined over time. My best guess is it's Wordpress headers causing this issue, as you said in #2. Please curl the Wordpress URL from the nginx server and post the headers that come back. I'll answer all your questions if I post a formal answer, but nothing you've said concerns me, inc #6.